# CircleCI using docker node:8 (debian) does not set up proper locale

Tags: docker, jestjs, circleci-2.0

I have CircleCI pipeline setup for my test flow using Jest snapshot and one of my snapshot tests keeps failing. I use Javascript to generate a Date object (`new Date("YYYY-MM-DD")`) and locally it yields MM/DD/YYYY but in the docker image (`node:8`) it yields YYYY-MM-DD instead so the snapshot test fails. I have tried to set up locales by:

```yml
docker:
  - image: circleci/node:8
    environment:
        TZ: "America/Los_Angeles"
        LANG: en_US.UTF-8
        LANGUAGE: en_US.UTF-8
        LC_ALL: en_US.UTF-8
```

But it complains it cannot set the default locale so I added:

```yml
- run:
        name: Reconfigure Locale
        command: sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

which seemed to be a solution for most of the people that had the same problem but not my case.

I also tried to have the same local docker image and test it there and it worked fine with these commands:

```
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y locales

RUN sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales && \
update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

So I tried these in circleci and sed commands complained about permissions even when it is called with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Okay just FYI, it was the node version caused the date format issue. I installed [full-icu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/full-icu) npm package which handles locale for the node application. To re-visit my problem, I had successfully installed locale and set it to be the same as the local machine but Node won't pick the locale from the system but from the browser being used. I hope this info helps.